# MySQL: Creating a database without root privileges

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a MySQL user that will only able to create a new user+database(+password) combinations - without being the *mysql root* user for obvious security concerns.

My idea is to have a secure user (`INSERT` privileges only) that will modify the `mysql` table directly, but I don't know if there are consequences.

To be clear, I want to create a user that will **only** be able to generate users+database+password combinations using an automated script that will run using that user. I want that user to operate on the least permissions as possible.

What are my other options?

Comment: might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/128740/mysql-grant-create-and-all-privileges-on-user-own-database

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the normal GRANT system in MySQL. But the user you're using will need all the same access they're trying to GRANT. You can only do GRANTs with the same permissions or less than your current user.

Don't start messing around with the system tables, it's not necessary.

Comment: I just created a user with only the `GRANT` privilege. I cannot create new database.

Comment: You need more than just the GRANT privilege. You will need to give the user other privileges as well. Refer to the MySQL docs for a list of privileges to grant.